# Is finding and using expired domains for backlinks considered Black-Hat?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, backlinks, blackhat

http://www.matthewwoodward.co.uk/tutorials/build-expired-web-2-0-networks-increase-rankings/

This guide shows how to identify and generate backlinks for a website.

If one was to follow this guide:

a. Is this a black hat technique?

b. Is this something that Google would penalise a website for doing?

c. What are better ways or other ways of getting good backlinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of what this article is referring to will get you into serious trouble with search engines. It is extremely poor advice and prime example why SEO is such a mess!

*Do not try and find tricks or magic buttons to push.*

Create high quality compelling content and stick with high quality SEO advice. We offer that here. Since most SEO sites are junk, at least come here first and see what the real day-to-day experts think. You will stay out of trouble that way.

Answer (score 0):

yes surely as the links coming from that site will take the user no where, and please try to build links on your own and not by submitting the site link on free link binding sites as they build bogus links that take the user nowhere.